# Transformation error: "The current event is not START_ELEMENT but 2"

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jax-ws

Similarly to an [older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578431/accessing-the-content-of-a-jax-ws-dispatch-response) I'm trying to access a web service with JAX-WS using:

```
Dispatch<Source> sourceDispatch = null;
sourceDispatch = service.createDispatch(portQName, Source.class, Service.Mode.PAYLOAD);
Source result = sourceDispatch.invoke(new StreamSource(new StringReader(req)));
System.out.println(sourceToXML(result));
```

where:

```
private static String sourceToXML(Source result) {
    Node rootNode= null;
    try {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
        DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();
        transformer.transform(result, domResult );
        rootNode = (Node) domResult.getNode();
  } catch (TransformerException e) {
        e.getMessage();
  }

    return rootNode.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
}
```

but I **get the error 'The current event is not START_ELEMENT null but 2'** (I think on the transformer)

What am I doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

Presumably from the parser. I would say a stack trace would be helpful, but Xerces/Xalan has a tendency for screwing those up.

Obvious steps to take:

- Try looking at the result as a string.
- Try parsing with a parser, ignoring the transformer for now.
- Try finding out exactly what the error was.

Answer (score 0):

You should amend your statement

```
e.getMessage()
```

to actually print the error message :-) That should help.

```
System.err.println(e.getMessage());
```

or preferably

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: Or better throw new Error(exc);